# Why hair particles don't stay where must be?

Tags: particles, hair

Always when I try to add hair, I've got the problem.
Hair don't stay where must be (over than red square in example).
People in youtube easier create hair but I've always got that. I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Example]

Comment: How many planes do you have? One red, one white, or just one?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the hair is set around the vertices of the vertex group  that you selected and not limited to the polygons. If you select a smaller polygon inside your (red? black?) polygon you will probably get the area you want.

Comment: @Kiskit
I have 1 plane with some red polygons
And in particle system's setings I set that red polygons how density. But they are go across that red square

Comment: So you have set particles density to a vertex group and that vertex group is the red area only?

Comment: @Kiskit yes, you are right

Comment: Maybe post your blend so we can have a look. It sounds like you're doing it correctly

Comment: @Kiskit I'm a little bit of stupid so explain pls how can I clip blend file to my question? Or you meant another way?

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file